# Where is the documentation for the CreatedBy object?

Tags: apex, soql, api, fields

Browsing salesforce topics on message boards I came across this code:

```
CaseComment comment = [SELECT CreatedById, CreatedBy.UserName FROM CaseComment];
```

It looks like CreatedBy is a field of CaseComment. However, CreatedBy doesn't appear as a field in the documentation for [CaseComment](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_casecomment.htm) nor is it listed in the documentation as a [standard object](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_list.htm).

Where is the documentation that covers the CreatedBy object?

Comment: Cory, be sure to accept whichever answer best answered your question, and upvote answers which were helpful.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no `CreatedBy` object --- the `CreatedById` reference field, along with `LastModifiedById` and `OwnerId`, is (except in rare cases) a reference to the `User` object. Thus, querying for `CreatedBy.UserName` on the `CaseComment` object is requesting the `UserName` field of the `User` record who created the `CaseComment` record.

If you were thrown off by the lack of a `__r` ending on the `CreatedBy` field to indicate that it is a reference to another object, you're not alone --- this is a common source of confusion for Force.com developers. Here's a quick reference to help you when dealing with Reference fields:

- Standard Object reference fields

  - Always end in `Id`, e.g. `CreatedById`, `ParentId`
  - Can point to / reference multiple objects (polymorphism)
  - Fields on related objects can be accessed by removing the `Id` from the field name, e.g. `CreatedBy.Email`, `Parent.Name`
- Custom Object reference fields

  - Always end in `__c`, e.g. `Survey_Question__c`
  - Will always point to a single object, e.g. to `Survey_Question__c`
  - Fields on related objects can be accessed by replacing the `__c` with `__r` on the field name, e.g. `Survey_Question__r.Prompt__c`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 9):

The System Fields documentation covers this (sort of):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/system_fields.htm

CreatedBy is the relationship to the User identified by the CreatedById on the record.

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Comment: The link got obsolete. Updated one is "System Field" - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/system_fields.htm?search_text=System%20Fields