# createdbyid lookup field reference, is it possible?

Tags: lookup, relationships, reference

I am trying to setup a lookup relationshiop for createdbyid as I have done for contact and account , as I am loading in migration data

for example for a custom object field i have called Constituent__C

i used

```
Constituent__r.external_id
```

and everything works great

but user object and audit fields are a little different

I tried doing this
Field is CreatedById so i attempted

```
CreatedBy.external_id
```

for the user module, and nothing happens

i used this SO to help me, but not getting any results [Where is the documentation for the CreatedBy object?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4413/where-is-the-documentation-for-the-createdby-object/4415)

Comment: Have you enabled the audit fields as mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Considerations-before-having-Create-Audit-Fields-enabled&language=en_US&type=1)

Comment: @RahulSharma that fixed it, make an answer and ill give you credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These standard fields- `Created By`, `Created Date`, `Last Modified By ID`, `Last Modified Date` are setup audit fields which are locked by default.

For migrating the legacy data, you would have to unlock audit fields <s>by logging a case with Salesforce.</s> (quoting from documentation):

> For a System Administrator to enable the feature they can follow the
>   click-path below:
>
> Setup | Customize | User Interface | **Enable "Set Audit Fields upon
>   Record Creation" and "Update Records with Inactive Owners" User
>   Permissions**

Here are some knowledge articles for reference-

1. [Enable Create Audit Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213290&type=1)
2. [Set audit field values for imported records (Created By, Created Date, Last Modified By ID, Last Modified Date)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=How-to-specify-the-values-in-Created-By-Created-Date-Last-Modified-By-ID-Last-Modified-Date&type=1)
3. [Considerations before having Create Audit Fields enabled](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Considerations-before-having-Create-Audit-Fields-enabled&language=en_US&type=1)
4. [Set Audit Fields and Update Records with Inactive Owners](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000227663&type=1)

Comment: Fun fact, you no longer have to open a case to enable this permission.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson for the information, I was not aware of it. Added information as per your comment.